# Arrays: Add number to Index 5 and Push Right

Tags: java, arrays

So basically, my problem is that I have to make the index 5 of an array = n and all numbers to the right pushes up one index. 
    public void addThisNumberToIndex5(int number)
      {
          // add number to the numbers array at index 5
          // all existing numbers should be shifted to the right.

```
      for (int i = 5; i < numbers.length+1; i++)
      {
          number[i] = number[i+1];
      }
      numbers[5] = number;
  }
```

I keep getting error: "array required, but int found" but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: what is `number` in your code.

Comment: Please make it compile first, that code up there probably doesn’t. Also, paste the whole code. How is `numbers` declared and initialized? That’s probably where your problem is.

Comment: @Bombe: I think "making it compile" is the OPs problem. =)

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line:

```
number[i] = number[i+1];
```

Now think about your two variables:

- `number` is of type `int`
- `numbers` is of type `int[]`

Now think about what you might want to change about that line.

The compiler is telling you all the information you need - you've written code which looks like it's *trying* to access an array, but you're trying to do it *on* an `int`. Hopefully it will also have told you the line number.

Rather than *just* fixing the error here, it's worth making sure you understand the situation well enough so that next time you'll be able to correct it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in line two. It should read "numbers" instead of "number".

Also, take care not to exceed the arrays boundaries! Maybe you need to create a new array that can store an additional value?

Answer (score 1):

You also can use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). It's a resizable-array implementation of the List interface. You can do something like this:

```
myArrayList.add(5, number);
```

The first parameter is the index you want to add the new item and the second one is your number. If your insert an element at index n, all other elements after that index "moves to the right". See the [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get arrayIndexOutOfBounds exception because in the last iteration you're trying to get `numbers[numbers.length+1]` which does not exist.
And you have a mistake.You missed 's' letters.
`number **s**[i] = number **s**[i+1];`
You should create a new array with length of the "numbers" array + 1. I think there's no need to explain what you should do after that ))